# Chrome Developer Tools CSS lines and stylesheet name not displaying

Tags: google-chrome

In Developer Tools in Google Chrome when i inspect an element in a page locally hosted on my pc , in the styles window the stylesheet:line-number is not showing. Example style.css:127 ...
What's the problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered this problem as well.  The folder name on the local server contained a space.  When I renamed the folder (used a hyphen instead of the space) the stylesheet filename and line numbers came up Developer Tools again.